# KEYUP Event in JQUERY for ASP.net Textbox

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, jquery

How to make **KEYUP** event in JQuery for a textbox on **ASP.net** webpage ? (not KEY PRESS event)

Comment: `$('element').on('keyup', function() {...});` <- like you would for anything else ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Say this is your textbox:

```
<input type='text' name='myTextbox' id='myTextbox'/>
```

Jquery for on keyup event

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#myTextbox").on('keyup',function(){
      alert('Key up');
      //Code 
   });
});
```